# Getting object from command so it can be used in conditional logical

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pretty basic question and concept that I don't know the answer to. I am playing with [Clamd 1.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/clamd/) and in the example it shows the following when using the CLI:

```
>>> import clamd
>>> cd = clamd.ClamdUnixSocket()
>>> cd.ping()
'PONG'
>>> cd.version()                             # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
'ClamAV ...
>>> cd.reload()
'RELOADING'
>>> open('/tmp/EICAR','wb').write(clamd.EICAR)
>>> cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')
{'/tmp/EICAR': ('FOUND', 'Eicar-Test-Signature')}
```

I want to be able to take the object `cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')` creates and use it in a conditional. Something like: `if FOUND then send email to administrator and notify the user`.

I'm just not understanding how to access the object that is created. How do you access it? Using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: How does the result look if nothing or something else has been found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')
{'/tmp/EICAR': ('FOUND', 'Eicar-Test-Signature')}
```

`cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')` returns a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You can access values in dictionaries by their keys. In this case, the key is `/tmp/EICAR`. The value for that key is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). To access a member of a tuple, you can do so just like you would with an array - `tuplename[index]`.

```
result = cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')
if (result['tmp/EICAR'][0] == 'FOUND'):
    print("Send email")
```

Similarly, the value `'Eicar-Test-Signature'` in this case can be accessed via `result['tmp/EICAR'][0]`. I don't know what the side effects of the `cd.scan` function are, but you could bypass the variable `result` entirely and just use `cd.scan('/tmp/EICAR')['/tmp/EICAR'][1]` to access `'Eicar-Test-Signature'`.

Keep in mind if the `cd.scan` function fails or returns something other than what you expect, the key `/tmp/EICAR` may not be in the dictionary (I don't how the `clamd` library works or what it does). In that case, you can check whether a key exists in a dictionary like this:

```
if '/tmp/EICAR' in result:
    print('key is present')
```